# How to modify last line of a file using python in linux

Tags: python-3.x, file

I have a `file.txt` which has a below content:

```
A "Hello, World!" program generally is a computer program that outputs or displays the message "Hello, World!". 
Such a program is very simple in most programming languages, and is often used to illustrate the basic syntax of a programming language. 
It is often the first program written by people learning to code.[1][2] It can also be used as a sanity test to make sure that a computer 
language is correctly installed, and that the operator understands how to use it

Hello world
```

At the very last line of the file, I have a sentence `Hello world` which I want to comment `#` so that it becomes `#Hello world`. How can I comment/uncomment the last line of file using python3. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it as simply as expected. One solution is to prepend `#` to the relevant line and rewrite the entire file.

`file.txt`:

```
A "Hello, World!" program generally is a computer program that outputs or displays the message "Hello, World!". 
Such a program is very simple in most programming languages, and is often used to illustrate the basic syntax of a programming language. 
It is often the first program written by people learning to code.[1][2] It can also be used as a sanity test to make sure that a computer 
language is correctly installed, and that the operator understands how to use it

Hello world
```

`main.py`:

```py
fname = "file.txt"

with open(fname, "r") as f:
  contents = f.readlines()

# Last line is at -1.
contents[-1] = '#' + contents[-1]

with open(fname, "w") as f:
  f.write("".join(contents))
```

`"".join(contents)` turns the list of lines back into a string.

Comment: Thanks for this good suggestion. What can I do if I want to remove the `#` from the last line

Comment: Instead of `contents[-1] = '#' + contents[-1]`, add `contents[-1] = contents[1:]`